# Strange error I can't do anything with the data frame but it's not empty

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-redshift, databricks

I'm running a query in scala using databricks with Spark 1.6.0 (Hadoop 1) to filter some URL's data that I have in redshift but once the query finish successfully, if I run a count on the data frame it shows that there is data on the data frame but I try to display the data or join the data the data frame appears to be empty, it doesn't display anything and can't make a join.

This is the code for getting the data into databricks

```
val df  = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")  
  .option("url", jdbcUrl)
  .option("tempdir", s"s3a://....")
  .option("query", s"select * from table where column like '%word1%word2%word3%' )
  .load()
```

The actual data is something like this

```
'https://www.asdfg.com/word1?word2=/word3/asdasdadasd'
```

or

```
'https://www.asdfg.com/word1?word2=%2Fword3%2Fasdasdadasd'
```

I can't understand why if i run a count I get results but for any other operation the data frame appears to be empty, any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: When you say appears to be empty, what do you mean? Spark dataframes are lazy, only evaluated for certain operations, like counts.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer i'm aware of the lazy evaluation, the data frame appears  to be empty because if a display de data doesn't show anything like an empty data frame if I make a count shows that there is data or if make a left join the data doesn't match but I know for a fact that there is more that one value that should match

Comment: You can try to collect a few lines of data and see what is in there.

Comment: the data is basically 'https://www.asdfg.com/word1?word2=%2Fword3%2Fword4' or 'https://www.asdfg.com/word1?word2=/word3/word4' where word4 are parameters like user id word1,word2,word3, are specific words  that i need to use as a filter because other wise the amount of data retrieved by the query will be much larger